# Simple replace does not work with û. Why?

Tags: php, replace, str-replace, utf8-decode

I don't get expect result when trying to search and replace a string in PHP...

```
//Decode into latin 8859-1
$nvalue = utf8_decode( $inner_value );                                    
//$nvalue = baden-wûrttemberg.csv
//Expected = baden-wûrttemberg.csv OK!

$n2value = str_replace( 'û','u', $nvalue );
//$n2value = baden-wûrttemberg.csv
//Expected = baden-wûrttemberg.csv WHY?
```

Example:

**Original**: Baden-WÃ»rttemberg

**After utf8_decode()**: baden-wûrttemberg

**After replace**: baden-wûrttemberg (Expected: baden-w**u**rttemberg)

Why doesn't replace work?

I want this replacement because I don't want store filenames with "weird" characters...

Comment: What programming language is this in? PHP?

Comment: Maby you could use multibyte string? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php

Comment: It is working for me here: https://3v4l.org/44o86

Comment: @sebastianbrosch - weird that it's not working here.

Comment: Based on the link @sebastianbrosch supplied it got me thinking. I tested exactly the same code and it did work. I removed the utf8_decoding from the $inner_value and it worked. I don't know why and that is frustating. If someone can help me understand - please do!

Comment: You need to make sure what is your input encoding and what is your desired output encoding. Often beginners de/encode too much. Btw, it should be *Baden-Württemberg* ;) Note the *ü*.

Comment: @hek2mgl - I would not see myself as a beginner, but I see what you mean. Thank you! :-) (I know it should be a deutsch u but I want to use it in filenames and it's general better to use letters that contains a-z ant any other chars!

Comment: I'm from Germany, it is an *ü* not a *deutsch u*. It needs to get replaced by `ue`, not by `u` if you want to use ASCII characters. However, today's file system's support utf-8.

Comment: @hek2mgl - You're absolutely right! Thank you :-)